# Hide variation info from cart item title in WooCommerce 3+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-variations

Ever since we upgraded to Woocommerce version 3 our order confirmations are showing huge titles that include the variation detail. I don't like how it looks and it breaks some important functionalities in some custom-made plugins.

Reference: [Order Name Showing Variations since update to WC version 3](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/order-name-showing-variations-since-update-to-version-3/)

There is a filter that can be used to disable this data displaying in the title called `woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attribute_name` from what I understand. But I have no idea where to apply the filter.

Is there a quick way to apply the filter to change it back to display as it did before?

Comment: In which page the product name display like this. Shop page or cart or single product page.

Comment: @Vigneshwaranvicky, the issue is that after WC3.0 the product names are shown differently in confirmation emails, on the edit order admin page, and on the view orders page (my account). Previously it would show just the product name and below the product name it would list the variation attributes. Now it shows the variation attributes as part of the product name, as well as listing them below the product name.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This filter should work returning a `false` value for `$should_include_attributes` first argument in [**`woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-variation-data-store-cpt.php#L243) filter hook this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', 'custom_product_variation_title', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_variation_title($should_include_attributes, $product){
    $should_include_attributes = false;
    return $should_include_attributes;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

It should just work as you expect.

---

**Update:** The shorter way is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_false' );
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

just works too.

Comment: I have tested this code and it worked exactly as I had hoped. Woocommerce and related plugins are now again showing products and their variations as it used to be (before WC 3.0).

Comment: I have question: this does work as intended but instead of attribute key  I get always 'test:'displayed but attribute value works fine. In wc-template-functions.php file I noticed that this is returned by this 'wp_kses_post( $meta->display_key )' any ideas why ?

Comment: @Zygimantas Hum… I didn't catch it all …I don't have the answer for the moment, sorry.

Comment: Figured it out it takes by the name not the slug and the name was test, sorry for bothering :)

Comment: What else is this filter affecting except titles on Cart page?

Answer (score 2):

A quick gotcha if you're using this filter to remove attributes from e-mail items. It appears that once an item has been written to an order the properties of it will not change.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 0):

As @freemason_17 pointed out, @LoicTheAztec's answer could potentially hide those details at other places as well so just to be sure I added a condition that would limit this to the cart page alone:

```
function custom_product_variation_title($should_include_attributes, $product){
    if(is_cart()) {
        $should_include_attributes = false;
        return $should_include_attributes;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', 'custom_product_variation_title', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
/* -------------------- Remove variation names from title ------------------- */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_attribute_in_product_name', '__return_false' );
```