# Replace a certain character in WooCommerce cart item variations title by a pipe

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

How to remove a comma separation from product attribute on my checkout.

Example:

```
Blue Black Raw Denim - 37, Slimfit
```

**37** is attribute product and **slimfit** is model product I want remove comma or replace with `|`. how can I do that?

For cart code like this :

```
<td class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
    <?php
      if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;';
      } else {
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
      }
```

If I delete this part item product name and attribute will gone but instead gone.
 I want replace comma with a `|`...

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Reference Image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should use a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_cart_item_name`** filter hook, where you will replace the coma by a pipe using **`str_replace()`** php function, this way:

```
// Tested on WooCommerce version 3+
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'custom_item_name', 10, 3 );
function custom_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    $new_item_name = str_replace(',', ' |', $item_name);
    return $new_item_name;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works. It will replace the coma by a pipe in cart and checkout items title.

---

Related answer: [WooCommerce 3.0 - hide variation info in product title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839975/woocommerce-3-0-hide-variation-info-in-product-title/44859111#44859111)

Comment: but if i see at database its still using coma not pipe how i can do that thanks.

Comment: @muhammadhusni If you want to remove the attributes from the title in variations, see this answer: [WooCommerce 3.0 - hide variation info in product title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839975/woocommerce-3-0-hide-variation-info-in-product-title/44859111#44859111) …  This answer remove that new WC 3+ stupid option