# Display variations attributes values as separate rows in Woocommerce cart / checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, custom-taxonomy

I have several **variable** products on our `https://alcocovers.com/shop/` The issue I am facing is: upon adding to the cart, [Dumpster Tarps](https://alcocovers.com/product/dumpster-tarps/) has item data listed on cart page, but product [Lugger Cover](https://alcocovers.com/product/lugger-cover/) doesn't. Here's a screenshot:
[image]
I thought there was some issue in the cart item data template I am using on the website, but I checked and nothing is broken (for reference here's the template code `https://pastebin.com/fswKRZ8a`). I disabled all custom templates and the results were the same. I also double checked that both products are setup in exactly the same way so I am at a loss what's the reason(s) behind this. Anyone who has an idea what would be causing this?

**Update #1:** A friend suggested maybe because Lugger Cover page has only one attribute that's why it doesn't list the item data on cart. But I created a [test page](https://alcocovers.com/product/test-123/) and this page also doesn't have item data listed on the cart...

**Update #2:** I added a third attribute to the [test page](https://alcocovers.com/product/test-123/) and now the item data shows up on the cart page. No clue why for products that have one/two attributes used on the product page, the item data doesn't show up on the cart. I rechecked the template files and there's no issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following, that will display your product variations attributes as separated rows, below the cart item title:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_attribute_in_product_name', '__return_false' );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). I hope it will work.

---

Related:

- [Remove attribute values from product variation title and show them on separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377644/remove-attribute-values-from-product-variation-title-and-show-them-on-separate-r/47380351#47380351)
- [Hide variation info from cart item title in WooCommerce 3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839975/hide-variation-info-from-cart-item-title-in-woocommerce-3/44859111#44859111)

Comment: This actually worked exactly how I wanted because it didn't remove the attributes from the link in product name listed in the cart.