# how to remove some items in cart permalink

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, cart, permalinks

i'm trying to remove some Variation from product permalink in cart :
Its like this:

Product xxxx**-105x25-left-side**

Dimension: xxx
Direction : left-side

product x (title only)

Dimension: xxx
Direction : left-side

Examples of variations in image below :

[image]

so i need clean product link in cart  only with product title nothing more in it!

i have found this hook :

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', '__return_null' );
but i don't know how to use it properly

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', '__return_null' );

i tried this  and no  better result  just removing entire link that is not what i was intent to

Comment: Your callback function would need to return the HTML code for the new product link.

Comment: You seem wanting to remove variation attributes from variation product name, and display those attributes apart, which has nothing to do with the product permalink… Is this correct?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec yes exactly remove from product name link and show it properly like product page in cart in next line

Comment: Use the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541435/display-variations-attributes-values-as-separate-rows-in-woocommerce-cart-chec/52592279#52592279

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks Alot man  man  2 codes it worked easy !!